# Jquery hover runs when it shouldn't

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make a navigation that uses hover on desktop and click on mobile.

I am using this to check the window size to determine if its a mobile or desktop user.

```
$(window).bind("resize", responsiveJs);
$(document).ready(function () {
  responsiveJs();
});
```

And inside the responsiveJs function is a if statement checking this

```
      if ($window.width() < 768) {
    // do soemthing
    console.log("Mobile")
  } else {

    $(".dropdown").mouseover(function(){}
```

The problem I am facing is that if the window is bigger than 768 the mouseover function runs as it should, but if I resize the window to mobile, the mouseover function keeps running, but if I refresh the page this problem disappears.

This drives me insane, I have tried using hover() but the problem is still there. Do anyone have a clue how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem I am facing is that if the window is bigger than 768 the mouseover function runs as it should, but if I resize the window to mobile, the mouseover function keeps running, but if I refresh the page this problem disappears.

It's because you still have `mouseover` bond to your `.dropdown`. If you want this it to stop goofing around, you must unbind it when time comes, by calling `unbind()`:

```
$('.dropdown').unbind('mouseover');
```

Also the reason this issue does not occur when you reload is because of the conditional binding - if window is smaller, then after reload you do not attach the handler unless size meets the threshold.

NOTE: as you should drop using `bind()` and `unbind()` in favor of `on()` and `off()` methods as `bind()` and `unbind()` are documented as deprecated and discouraged.

Comment: I would check the width inside the mouseover, rather than having to conditionally bind and unbind the handler over and over and ...

Comment: I'd too, yet optimalisation was not my goal with this answer.